# Download page source of multiple site's easily

Tags: html, excel, web

I need to obtain the source code (unedited) from 245 specific URL's
to then import into excel where I've already setup some filtering, text2columns etc to extract the specific information I need from each page..

I could open all 245 pages manually, view source, highlight, copy, open excel, paste etc.. but I am confident there is an easier way???

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl to download the web pages and save them to a file. For example:

```
curl -L www.google.com > google.com
```

-L will follow redirects.

For multiple files you can use:

```
curl -L -O http://www.example.com/page1.html -O http://www.example.com/page2.html
```

This will create 2 files page1.html and page2.html in the current directory.

You can download curl for your environment from:
https://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Comment: Thanks.. I'm at work at the minute but will download and test later.. one quick question..

`curl -L www.google.com/page1.html > google.txt
curl -L www.google.com/page2.html > google.txt`

If I was to do the above, would it put page2.html on the bottom of page1 in the txt file or overwrite?

Comment: This would overwrite the file. I have edited the answer to show how to get the content from multiple urls and save to individual files.